# 451 Temporary local issue with sending out emails

Tags: linux, email, email-server, exim, email-bounces

```
2012-06-14 21:57:14 cwd=/etc/csf 4 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -f alerts@host2.thetimesoftimes.com -t
2012-06-14 21:57:14 1SfEIE-0000wK-Kj <= alerts@host2.thetimesoftimes.com U=root P=local S=678 T="lfd on host2.thetimesoftimes.com: WHM/cPanel root access alert from 181.21.53.1 (US/United States/" for alertme@thetimesoftimes.com
2012-06-14 21:57:14 cwd=/var/spool/exim 3 args: /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1SfEIE-0000wK-Kj
2012-06-14 21:57:23 1SfEIE-0000wK-Kj == alertme@thetimesoftimes.com R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp defer (-44): SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<alertme@thetimesoftimes.com>: host direct-connect.thetimesoftimes.com [76.23.22.22]: 451 Temporary local problem - please try later
2012-06-14 21:57:23 1SfEIE-0000wK-Kj ** alertme@thetimesoftimes.com: retry timeout exceeded
2012-06-14 21:57:23 cwd=/var/spool/exim 7 args: /usr/sbin/exim -t -oem -oi -f <> -E1SfEIE-0000wK-Kj
2012-06-14 21:57:23 1SfEIN-0000wQ-Em <= <> R=1SfEIE-0000wK-Kj U=mailnull P=local S=1811 T="Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender" for alerts@host2.thetimesoftimes.com
```

Not sure what this means or what is wrong. Is this an Exim configuration error?

under /etc/localdomains I have hosts2.domain and under /etc/remotedomains i have the main domain listed. Do I need to configure Exim now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line tells you it is a temporary error and exim should be retrying to send at regular intervals for at least 5 days or so. That is the default.

```
2012-06-14 21:57:23 1SfEIE-0000wK-Kj == alertme@thetimesoftimes.com R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp defer (-44): SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<alertme@thetimesoftimes.com>: host direct-connect.thetimesoftimes.com [76.23.22.22]: 451 Temporary local problem - please try later
```

But in your case exim fails delivery right away:

```
2012-06-14 21:57:23 1SfEIE-0000wK-Kj ** alertme@thetimesoftimes.com: retry timeout exceeded
```

I do not know why the remote server gives this temporary error, if you control the server check its logs to find out.

I also do not know why exim in your case would timeout retrying and send a permanent failure back to you right away. But I suspect you may have (mis)configured it to do that? The default exim configuration wouldn't behave that way.

Sometimes, in case of "retry time not reached for any host" in order to force a retry right away on a debian system I would delete the file /var/spool/exim4/db/retry and then start another queue run. You may try that, but I am not sure if it's going to be effective with your particular problem. It's just a quick fix that's worth a try (it pretty harmless), but for a permanent fix double check your configuration to see what exim's behaviour is with regards to temporary failures.

You start a queue run with:

```
exim -q -v
```

For more exim commands see this cheat sheet: http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/exim_cheatsheet.php

Comment: The spam software that I use gives a 451 response to every new inbound IP it sees upon initial connection.  Legitimate mail servers will wait a few minutes to try again.  Most Spammers won't.

Comment: Yes that's the correct behaviour of an MTA, including exim. It's most likely a configuration issue that can be easily fixed.